# Mercurial collapses lines into single line when piping output

Tags: shell, redirection, pipe, interactive

I'd like to sort based on the output of a mercurial (hg) command.  The output from `hg log` is collapsed into 1 line when piping to another command but I want to keep separate lines.

Here's a minimum reproducible case:

```
# Initial setup
mkdir /tmp/hgbug; cd /tmp/hgbug; hg init; 
touch README.md; hg add README.md
h commit -m "initial commit"

# Bug - the echo command replaces a complex find command
echo '1a\n2b\n3c\n' | xargs -I % hg log --template '%' | sort

# Actual Output
# 1a2b3c

# Expected Output
# 1a
# 2b
# 3c
```

The interesting part is that mercurial doesn't collapse the lines when the output isn't piped or redirected.

```
echo '1a\n2b\n3c\n' | xargs -I % hg log --template '%'
# Actual Output
# 1a
# 2b
# 3c
```

How do I prevent mercurial from collapsing lines when redirecting output?

To clarify, here's a more complete example comparing the output of `hg` with `echo` using both `xargs` and a `while` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp/hgbug

echo '# hg log - xargs'
echo $'1a\n2b\n3c' | xargs -I {} hg log --template "hg-{}" | sort

echo
echo '# plain echo - xargs'
echo $'1a\n2b\n3c' | xargs -I {} echo "echo-{}" | sort

echo
echo '# hg log - while read'
echo $'1a\n2b\n3c' | while read -r file; do hg log --template "hg-$file"; done | sort

echo
echo '# plain echo - while read'
echo $'1a\n2b\n3c' | while read -r file; do echo "echo-$file"; done | sort
```

That script outputs the following:

```
# hg log - xargs
hg-1ahg-2bhg-3c

# plain echo - xargs
echo-1a
echo-2b
echo-3c

# hg log - while read
hg-1ahg-2bhg-3c

# plain echo - while read
echo-1a
echo-2b
echo-3c
```

Comment: `xargs` sets a parameter for each line extracted from the input. It is up to the target program to decide how to handle multiple parameters. If you need one parameter at a time, don't use `xargs`; instead, use `find ... -exec hg log --template {} \;` or `find ... | while read -r file; do hg log --template "$file"; done` (note my use and omission of quotes).

Comment: I still don't understand where the output is getting collapsed. `GNU xargs` with the `-I` param implies `-L 1`, or one line per invocation.  So, there's 3 `hg log` invocations.  I'd like to stick with `xargs` to use the parallelism feature.  If I use echo instead of hg, everything works as expected.

Comment: I added a more complete example comparing `hg` to `echo` to help illustrate the problem.

Comment: Turns out the while-read was a red-herring.  The problem was `hg log` doesn't add trailing newlines when output is redirected.  The behavior makes sense, but is surprising when trying to figure out the differences between interactive and redirected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hg log` doesn't add a trailing newline to output when the `--template` flag is set **and** the shell command is redirected or piped to another command.

To make it work, you need to add the newline to the template string like so:

```
echo '1a\n2b\n3c\n' | xargs -I % hg log --template '%\n' | sort
# Output
1a
2b
3c
```